# Can I connect two private addressed BLE devices together?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, private, mac-address

*Hello,*

**The context:**  I'm currently working on a BLE device that is connected with Just Works connection type to its Master (android tablet).

Since :

> Android devices with recent versions of Android do not use the public address when connecting. Rather, they use a random address. This is part of the BLE spec. For the purpose of privacy, in addition to the public device address there are random device addresses. New versions of Android uses a random address when connecting to peripherals. ([source of that quote](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/73434/different-peer-address-each-time/))

I understood that my Android tablet is using a random address. For that, i made a programme to verify this information and it actually works (fortunately).

So my BLE public addressed device can connect to the master by receiving its pairing ask.

---

**The question:** First of all, what exactly are BLE addresses (random, static, public(mac) it's a bit confusing from the docs) ?

**The MAIN question:** Can my master (android tablet) connect to my device when those two are private addressed ?

---

**My specifications:**

- Using VisualStudio
- Using VisualGDB and openOCD
- BLE_lib.h and BlueNRG

Ask for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: Public BLE address is given by Bluetooth SIG and is guaranteed to unique. Random BLE address does not have this property. In addition random address can be either static or public. Static address cannot be changed while the BT chip is on. Public is divided into resolvable and non-resolvable, both can change whenever and the basic difference is the amount of bytes that change.

The main answer: Yes but you will need a way to identify the device. You could broadcasting specific data (e.g. manufacturer data or a 128b service UUID) and have your tablet scan for it. Then you can connect to whatever address you find provided the device advertises correct data.

And recommendation: You can find a lot of stuff at Nordic semiconductor-related sites. Even if you do not use their stack, their tutorials and explanations are easy to understand and cover pretty much everything.

Edit: I could probably provide better answer if I knew what exactly you intend to do.

Comment: The answer to the answer : Thanks it's clear !
The answer to the main answer : Thanks it's clear !
The answer to the recommendation : thanks for it, I'm using it often but i couldn't find any answer like you did.

Benjamin

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the link in your answer without registering where it led :) Anyway, the advertisement I talked about is well described [here](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/tutorials/5/), there is also a link to a similar question concerning types of addresses.